# How to handle error in Given/When/Then statements and AfterScenario hook if error pops in both blocks

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I got a scenario

```
@walk
Given a man is standing
When he starts moving
Then he covers 5 meters

[BeforeScenario("walk")]
public void BeforeWalkScenario()
{
       SetEnvironmentForWalk();
}


[AfterScenario("walk")]
public void AfetrWalkScenario()
{
       ClearWalk();
}
```

In my test, execution is failing on 'When' statement and error is produced. Also, since I have a AfterScenario as well, it also get's executed after the error.

Unfortunately, my test is again failing in AfterScenario block. Due to this, in test report only AfterScenario error is noted and reported. How can I make sure my testresult report also shows the reason for failure on When statement.

Help would be appreciated. New to BDD. Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to have a try catch block for every step definition.. since they are hell lot of them.. I want just the exact appium generated error should also get printed in test execution result doc

Answer (score 2):

In ScenarioContext.TestError you get the last thrown exception from your bindings. 
You can check this in your hooks.

See http://www.specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/